# Trent Richardson inline DateTimePicker defaultValue always shows 00:00 on alt field

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

below is my jquery code for initialising the dateTimePicker, but the documentation for the DefaultValue is sparse, as is the AltField documentation, so this is my best guess, but clearly isn't working, and always the time portion is showing 00:00 in the AltField :

```
$("#dateTimeField").datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    altTimeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    firstDay: 1, showTime: false,
    hourText: "tunti",
    minuteText: "min",
    altField: "#TextBox1",
    altFieldTimeOnly: false,
    showButtonPanel: false,
    defaultValue: '23:59', // default time
    defaultDate: -5,

});
```

The documentation for this 'defaultValue' option simply states:

> defaultValue : 
>   Default: null - String of the default time value placed in the input on focus when the input is empty.

The normal jQuery defaultDate option is showing correctly in the altField, but I need to show a default time of 23:59 also in the field.

Can anyone spot what I'm missing?

Comment: Just a question, is your alt field just showing time ? And your main field showing date ? If that the case, you should maybe remove "showTime : false" and set "altFieldTimeOnly" to "true". If you have some reasons for doing it in an other way, i'd like to know why ! :)

Comment: The altField is showing date and time due to the fact that the dateTimePicker is showing inline in Div #dateTimeField, and I also want to display the date and time in a TextBox, hence the use of the altField. I'm open to better suggestions tho :)

Comment: Ok i understand what's your problem now, i'm searching how to fix it =o

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question, what does the datepicker have to do with Cleveland Browns running back Trent Richardson?

Comment: Trent Richardson in this case is the DateTimePicker developer's name..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finaly the solution wasn't that complicated.

Consider using "hour" and "minute" option to solve your problem.

```
hour :
    Default: 0 - Initial hour set.

minute :
    Default: 0 - Initial minute set.
```

Finally you'll have something like that :

```
$("#dateField").datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    altTimeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    firstDay: 1, showTime: false,
    hourText: "tunti",
    minuteText: "min",
    altField: "#altField",
    altFieldTimeOnly: false,
    showButtonPanel: false,
    hour: 23,
    minute: 59, // default time
    defaultDate: -5,
});
```

Here is a [WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rKYPA/2/) that initalise time to "23:59" and day to "-5".

Hope it helped you.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thanks so much.